# Matlab keyboard shortcut not working with hebrew

Tags: matlab, keyboard, hebrew

I have changed my keyboard preferences to Windows Default Set. Matlab 
R2012a + Ubuntu 12.04. I have the keyboard in English, when I enter an additional shortcut to add to the preferences, you can see in the image that it is somehow reading it as Hebrew and therefore none of keyboard shortcut work. Any ideas?

[Preferences image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrxlc.png)

Comment: This is really better suited for Mathworks Support

Answer (score 1):

In the Environment section of the Home tab, click the Preferences button and navigate to Keyboard -> Shortcuts.  Under Active Settings, select "Windows Default Set", if you want to use windows based shortcuts e.g. Copy (Ctrl+C) and Paste (Ctrl+V).

Windows based shortcuts may not work if "Emacs Default Set" is selected under Active Setting tab.

Comment: I have already done that. For example Shift+Insert works but not any shortcut that uses keys that map to letters in the Hebrew alphabet.